Invalid Authorization Specification - running SSIS packages on SQL Server 2022
I'm trying to run an SSIS package on SQL Server 2022.
It fails with the error:

Invalid Authorization Specification.

I can run the SSIS package from my local machine & other servers, just not from the SQL Server 2022 Virtual Machine.
The Connect String is as follows:
Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=MyVMName;

What I have tried:

Installing the latest OLE DB Driver 19 on the VM.
Specifying the driver in the connection string. again, it works on my local machine but not when running the ssis package from the SQL Server 2022 VM.
Running as 32 & 64 bit.
Note - connecting from a UDL on the SQL Server 2022 VM, using Microsoft OLEDB provider for SQL Server succeeds.

None of the above has worked.
I would appreciate any advice on how to get this working.

You've probably already checked this, but have you made sure the account that runs your package on the VM has access to the data source?

is the VM part of the domain where the sql server is?

The package is running under the sql server agent local account, which is sysadmin (NT SERVICE\SQLServerAgent)

SQL Server hosting the source database, ssis catalog & sql agent is all the same machine. I am using network names, not localhost, and yes, the machine is domain joined.

Try Integrated Security=true or Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=True

Well, I got this solved. not exactly sure why these steps fixed the issue but they did.

reinstall the oledb 19 driver.
create brand new ssis project, test that it worked and copied the connection string. it was quite different from the previous one, quite a few new parameters. setting the trust certificate to true and encrypt to false.
removed "encryptSensitiveWithUserKey" as it started failing validation. unsure why this didnt happen on the older sql 2016 instance.

It now works, and although i would like to know why these steps fixed it, I dont have remaining time to spend on this.
Thanks for the help all
